# Get Dictionary of Users Uid on Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

This is my case; I need a dictionary of all of the users in my app to use `didSelectRowAt` on a `UITableView` to get the searched users `uid`.
my `firebase` database is designed like this:
**not allowed to upload Images so link here**
[image: not allowed to upload Images so link here]

Also, I succesfully made a `string/dictionary` of the users names by doing this;

```
        let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
    let query = rootRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "users")
    query.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            if let value = child.value as? NSDictionary {
               // declaring a user in class User() which was made with strings(name, email, ect.)
            let user = User()

            let name = value["name"] as? String ?? "name not found"
            // making the string of it go into the user.name
            user.name = name
            // appending it into a variable of class user()
            self.users.append(user)
            }
     }
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this because the `uid's` are all different and don't have a name to it `(ex.  email: test@test.com).`

Perhaps I need to restructure my database to allow this but I'm not too sure. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to keep a field for uid along with the name, email and profileImageURI fields.

```
let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
guard let uid = rootRef.child("users").childByAutoId().key
```

Now, send the uid as a field while saving the data to firebase.
While retrieving the data you can map the data as follows :

```
let query = rootRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "users")
query.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        if let value = child.value as? NSDictionary {
           // declaring a user in class User() which was made with strings(name, email, etc.)
        var dict = [String:String]()
        let user = User()
        let name = value["name"] as? String ?? "name not found"
        // making the string of it go into the user.name
        user.name = name
        user.uid = value["uid"]
        dict[name] = "\(uid)"
        }
 }
```